# How can i create from 2 functions just one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First function create a table with data from :

```
    var buildTable = function () {
    for (var i = 0, l = userData.length; i < l; i++) {
        buildTd(userData[i]);
    }
    $("#users").html(divData);

};
```

This is the first function :

```
var buildTd = function (data) {
    divData += '<tr id =' + data.id + '>' +
        '<td>' + data.username + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.level + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.regstatus + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.regdate + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-info" value="Edit" onclick="userList.editUser(' + data.id + ')">Edit</button>' + ' ' +
        '<button class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onclick="userList.deleteRow(' + data.id + ')">Delete</button>' + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

};
```

This is the second function :

```
var buildnewTd = function (data) {
    var html = '<tr id = ' + data.id + '>' +
        '<td>' + data.username + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.level + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.regstatus + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.regdate + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-info"value="Edit" onclick="userList.editUser(' + data.id + ')">Edit</button>' + ' ' +
        '<button class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onclick="userList.deleteRow(' + data.id + ')">Delete</button>' + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $("#users").append(html);
};
```

I want to combine both beacause i dont want my code to repeat how can i do that?:D

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the invariants between the two functions? That would put you on the right track.

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi can you give me an exemple i`m noob and now i`m just learning :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var buildnewTd = function (data) {
var html = '<tr id = ' + data.id + '>' +
    '<td>' + data.username + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.level + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.regstatus + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.regdate + '</td>' +
    '<td>' +
    '<button class="btn btn-info"value="Edit" onclick="userList.editUser(' + data.id + ')">Edit</button>' + ' ' +
    '<button class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" onclick="userList.deleteRow(' + data.id + ')">Delete</button>' + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
if($("tr").index(this) != 0){
    $("#users").append(html);
}
};
```

try this

Comment: i tryed but buildTd  is undefined because of the first function that create the table ...

Comment: you'll have to change the function name to buildnewTd(userData[i]);

Comment: done i made it i had to change $("#users").html(divData); to $("#users").html(); thanks a lot:D